# How to disable button event on JavaFX 8 until http response

Tags: java, http, javafx

Using JavaFx8 i have a button that send a http request. I want to disable this button until i received the answer from the server. My situation is the following:

```
HBox boxRep = new HBox();
...
boxRep.setOnMousePressed((event) ->{
      String responseHttpCode = "";
      responseHttpCode = MySendHttp(ip, port, request);
      ...
      });
```

My method (MySendhttp) return the String with the http code status (200,404...). I dont't want to send another request until the server answer.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Run it in a task, on a background thread, and process the response in the `onSucceeded` handler:

```
boxRep.setOnMousePressed(event -> {
    Task<String> httpTask = new Task<String>() {
        @Override
        public String call() throws Exception {
            return MySendHttp(ip, port, request);
        }
    };

    Thread thread = new Thread(httpTask);

    httpTask.setOnSucceeded(e -> {
        boxRep.setDisable(false);
        String responseCode = httpTask.getValue();
        // process...
    });


    boxRep.setDisable(true);

    thread.start();
});
```

Comment: Thank, I've tried this solution but give me an error on boxRep.setDisable(true): Local variable boxRep defined in an enclosing scope must be final or effectively final

Comment: @Soul85 Why are you modifying `boxRep`? You will only get that error if you assign it more than once.

Comment: Please edit the question to clarify it, instead of posting code in comments (which is unreadable). What you posted here, as far as I can tell, would not cause that error, so please be precise.

Comment: Sorry, my comment wasn't clear. Your solution works, i assigned boxRep two times. Thanks